# Why is the ActionCreators property undefined in my _reduxDevtools object using redux devtools?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, redux, redux-devtools

Following the document on the [official repo](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools), when I create a *DevTools* component, a *configureStore* store and render the *DevTools* component in my main component in my *working* react app, I end up with an:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined` in *LogMonitor.js:45*.

Line 45 corresponds to:`var reset = _reduxDevtools.ActionCreators.reset;`

`_reduxDevtools` looks like this:

```
▼ _reduxDevtools: Object
    __esModule: true
    ► devTools: devTools()
    ► persistState: persistState(sessionId)
    ► __proto__: Object
```

The `ActionCreators` property is, in fact, missing.

**Why is the `ActionCreators` property undefined in my `_reduxDevtools` object?**

Am I missing something obvious? My application is working well when I don't use `redux-devtools` so I highly doubt it's coming from my app's code.

I also `rm -rf`*ed* my node_modules and reinstalled everything.

### Update

I tried to reproduce the issue using [the counter example](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/tree/master/examples/counter) of `redux-devtools` and tried to see how my project and this example differ.

If I remove [this line](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/blob/master/examples/counter/webpack.config.js#L21) from *webpack.config.js* on the counter example, I have the same error message:

```
'redux-devtools': path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'src')
```

> [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias): Replace modules by other modules or paths.

Comment: It looks to me like you're doing everything correctly. I suggest raising an issue at the redux-devtools GitHub page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're using an outdated version of `redux-devtools` while using the new API first introduced in the [v3.0.0-beta-2](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta-2).

You can also see this by looking at the peer dependencies of the dock and log monitor plugins, that they require devTools v3.

I'm guessing you got this error since when you installed, the stable release wasn't out yet and npm didn't pick the beta version, leaving you with the v2.

I bumped the `redux-devtools` version from your reprod to the last one and everything worked perfectly

---

Also, the resolve param of the webpack configuration in the examples is only there to require devTool source from the root of the repository without having to install it again.